# Jade rendering error with two scripts, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, express, pug

Here is the offending portion of my index.jade file:

```
script(type="text/javascript")
  if user
    | window.user = !{user};
  else
    | window.user = 'null';
  if category
    | window.category = !{category};
  else
    | window.category = 'null';
  if postid
    | window.postid = !{postid};
  else
    | window.postid = 'null';
script(src="all.js")
```

I've tested things, and my variables user, category, and postid are being sent to Jade correctly. However, on render, I get the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

that points to the start of the file, and the value of window.postid is set to "all.js". Clearly, something is funky. The category and postid are set by url parameters, and the site works fine in the case of neither category nor postid being set ('/') or when only the category is set ('/:category'). However, as I mentioned, the postid is being sent to Jade correctly on ('/:category/:postid') and I can, for instance, use it to set the title of the page to the value I want, but I can't seem to assign that value to window.postid without setting window.postid to the src value of the following script tag.

Comment: This Jade code looks correct and compiles properly into HTML. I guess the error is elsewhere, in some script. The `Unexpected token <` error often comes with a broken JSON.

Comment: Can't find the mistake, but I'm noticing one further peculiarity: Not only is window.postid set to the value of the src in the following script tag (all.js), but all.js is set to the rendered contents of the index.jade file, and the index is renamed to what should've been the value of window.postid... ???

Answer (score 1):

I put a log statement in my render function and found that it was being called three different times, once with the value of postid that I specified, and twice more with the values of all.css and all.js - I'm assuming that the Jade template was making extra get requests for these files and their names were being set to the value of postid.

I was essentially trying to have my routing handled by having the value of the url parameters passed to the main app at '/' as variables. For instance, `/category/page` would be routed to '/' with local variables category="category" and page="page". It didn't quite work.

My next try to get the desired effect will be to render index.jade for '/*' and to handle URL routing on the front end with hashes.